# How to generate symfony 3.x documentation?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

Is there any tool (method )to generate code documentation for Symfony 3.x? For example, the tool should generate classes methods, fields etc.

Comment: [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)?

Comment: do you think it's going to work for whole set of pages?

Comment: Take a look at the software, it was created exactly for this purpose (only configuration is a bit tricky, I often download lots of 3rd party sites that are just linked by mistake). And I bet there are others like this

Comment: As the link from the bottom of the page is telling you, you can actually recreate that same documentation thanks to [Sami](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/sami), a kind of PHPDoc generator that runs on code and creates documentation based on commented code.

Comment: That said, this question does not really fit in Stack Overflow because we tend not to address _Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 1):

Run Sami in your symfony path or clone symfony repository and run sami on src folder. Every time symfony is updated must run sami in order to re-generate the API documenation.

https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/sami

Comment: in fact, I am not looking for documentation generation tools. I was asking to download the http://api.symfony.com/3.2/index.html offline so I don't need to go online.

Comment: Can you please assist to find some tool so I may save api locally for offline use?